# How to show zero before decimal point in bc?

Tags: bc

```
echo "scale=3;1/8" | bc
```

shows `.125` on the screen. How to show `0.125` if the output result is less than one?

Comment: Crosslink: Same question on StackOverflow: [Bash script: specify bc output number format - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965411/bash-script-specify-bc-output-number-format)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`bc` can not output zero before decimal point, you can use [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

```
$ printf '%.3f\n' "$(echo "scale=3;1/8" | bc)"
0.125
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe into awk

```
echo "scale=3;1/8" | bc | awk '{printf "%.3f\n", $0}'
```

or you could just use awk for it all

```
awk '{printf "%.3f\n", 1/8}' <<< ""
```

#### Output

```
0.125
```

Comment: Why should we do `<<< ""`?

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia awk requires an input file to work, this creates and empty `here string`. So basically pretends there is an empty file at the end, otherwise awk will read from stdin.More info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)

Comment: @JID: Not all shell supported here string, you need to specify it for others viewers. Using `BEGIN` block prevent you from that trouble and it's portable.

Answer (score 1):

Bettering @cuonglm's answer:

```
a=10.543; b=`printf '%.6f' "$(echo "$a/100" | bc -l)"`; echo $b;
```

Use "bc -l" to use math library.